# Binary XML File causing FC?

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, binary, launch

I am simply trying to launch an activity from a button but when I do I am getting the following error in LogCat:

```
06-24 23:12:08.823: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(690): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #193: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

not sure if this helps any but here is the code for the button:

```
public void onClick(View src) {

    switch(src.getId()){

    case R.id.button18Holes:
        //*********************************//
        //***LAUNCHES ACTUAL APPLICATION***//
        //*********************************//

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(src.getContext(), EasyPar.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        break;
    }
```

Not exactly sure what Binary XML File is???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in one of your xml layout files, and probably the one for your EasyPar Activity.  Your exception says:

```
You must supply a layout_width attribute
```

Check your layouts to see where you have forgotten to specify a width.

Comment: Thank you... I forgot before I stopped coding last week I created a linear layout and left it blank in my main activity xml file, and once I cleared that out, it ran just fine.  Sometimes I guess I just need to search a bit more, thanks!  Will accept in 8 mins!

Answer (score 0):

Have you forgotten to set the layout with in your xml file in the layout folder?